# PHP ODBC - connection not working properly

Tags: php, mysql-odbc-connector

I wrote this code for the `ODBC` connection. But, I'm getting like this error. My `DB` is an MS Access database. Please, can anyone help me?

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$conn=odbc_connect('finance','','');
if (!$conn)
  {exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);}
$sql="SELECT * FROM Customers";
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
if (!$rs)
  {exit("Error in SQL");}
echo "<table><tr>";
echo "<th>Name</th>";
echo "<th>CustomerID</th></tr>";
while (odbc_fetch_row($rs))
{
  $Name=odbc_result($rs,"Name");
  $CustomerID=odbc_result($rs,"CustomerID");
  echo "<tr><td>$Name</td>";
  echo "<td>$CustomerID</td></tr>";
}
odbc_close($conn);
echo "</table>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is my error.**

```
    Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [FINANCE ODBC]Base table:Customers not found., SQL state S0002 in SQLExecDirect in C:\xampp\htdocs\odbc\index.php on line 11
Error in SQL
```

Comment: check if there is a Customers table

Comment: I checked `Customers` table is there

Comment: Try this **odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$yourebdFilename", '"", "");**

Comment: some syntax error

Comment: please, anyone can give the answer to this?